# tf.norm error ValueError: 'ord' must be a supported vector norm, got fro

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, neural-network, norm

I am trying to calculate the Frobenius Norm of my tensor

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072,20],stddev=0.1))
temp = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(W),W)
fro_W = tf.norm(temp, ord ='fro')
```

This produces the following error:

ValueError: 'ord' must be a supported vector norm, got fro

I don't understand why it is treating my 2D tensor as a vector and not as matrix.

Am I missing something here?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm):

> The Frobenius norm fro is not defined for vectors

Also,

> If axis is `None` (the default), the input is considered a vector

Try this instead:

```
tf.norm(temp, ord='fro', axis=(0,1))
```